# Events in Backbone.js nested views

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, backbone-events

I have a view called `DashboardView` that instantiates multiple `WidgetView`s. Each widget needs to have its own event bindings. So far as I can tell, these bindings get lost when the view is rendered and added to the parent view, i.e.:

```
class DashboardView extends Backbone.View
  constructor: -> 
    context = @
    _.each @collection, (w)->
      dv = new app.WidgetView(model: w)
      context.$el.append(dv.render()) 

class WidgetView extends Backbone.View
  events: 
     "click .config" : "config_widget"

  render: ->
      _.template($("#widget-template").html(), @model)
```

Doing it this way, the click events on the `.config` element of the widget are now lost. Is there a better way of mixing the nested views into the parent while ensuring that the event handlers on the child view are channelled correctly?

One solution I have seen to this problem comes in [this article](http://www.readability.com/articles/0px4nxtc). This looks about right, but I'm curious if there is a more elegant way of solving this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
class DashboardView extends Backbone.View
  constructor: -> 
    @collection.each ( w ) =>
      dv = new app.WidgetView( model: w )
      @$el.append dv.render().el // Append widget's @el explicitly

class WidgetView extends Backbone.View
  tagName: 'div' // or whatever your view's root element is

  template: _.template $( "#widget-template" ).html() // pre-compile template

  events: 
    "click .config": "config_widget"

  render: ->
    @$el.html @template @model.toJSON() // append template to @el
    return this // return view
```

So, the idea is this:

(1) Inside the `WidgetView`'s `render` method, you populate `@el` (the root element of the view) with its model's data via the template. (And notice how I compile the template **only once** - there is no need to compile the template on each render operation.)

(2) Inside the `DashboardView`, you append the widget's root element - `@el` - to the DOM.

The thing is that the view's events delegate to its root element - `@el`. Therefore, you want to work with the root element explicitly: inside `render`, you populate it, and then you append it to the DOM.

Comment: You could avoid the `context` stuff by using [`(w) =>`](http://coffeescript.org/#fat_arrow). And `@collection` should be Underscore-ified already so `@collection.each (w) =>` is another option.

Comment: @mu Cool `:)` Didn't know about the fat arrow.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that `delegateEvents` expects a single, non-changing element for your view.  Because your `render` function creates a new element every time, the bindings made by `delegateEvents` are never fired when you click on the element generated by `render`.

Luckily the current version of Backbone offers a [`setElement` method](http://backbonejs.org/#View-setElement) that will reassign your element with the argument you provide, and then it will automatically call `delegateEvents`.

Comment: One thing I should have made clear is I have multiple widgets instantiated in one dashboard. So reassigning the element is not exactly what I want, I think.